# google drive api access code life

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

How long is the access code valid for when a google drive api based app has been approved?

Can I save this code in my app and re-use it to avoid needing a human to authorize it repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An access token expires in one hour, while a refresh token (that can be used to request new access tokens) lasts until the user revokes access to the app.

You are recommended to store the refresh token for the user's future requests, but should take into account that the token can be invalid any time and react accordingly.

For more details on how to handle authorization in Google Drive apps, check https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Comment: Thanks bud! The "...lasts until the user revokes access" is precisely what I needed to know/figure out :).  In my testing it seems that if the access code is successfully used 1 time, then it doesn't work on the very next try.  The refresh token works perfectly for my needs (scripts to check for document updates for edu web site).